# If $f(x)>g(x)$ for some interval then is it right to say $\lim(f(x))\geq\lim(g(x))$ at the extreme point of that interval?

Tags: limits

If $f(x) >g(x)$ for $x\in(2,5)$ and $f(x),g(x)$ are defined for all real values of $x$ and $\text{lim}(f(x))$ at $2$ and $\text{lim}(g(x))$ at $2$ exist where $2$ is the extreme point of the interval then is it correct to say $\text{lim}(f(x)) \geq \text{lim}(g(x))$ at $2$?

Comment: @Ramanujan I would rather say that if the maps are continuous then $\ge$ holds. Continuity is not mandatory though.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net This is more accurate, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true since you've given that the limits are defined at $x=2$.

This is a limit inequality theorem. Please see the proof here (theorem 2.23):
[https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m125a/intro_analysis_ch2.pdf](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ehunter/m125a/intro_analysis_ch2.pdf)

$g(x) < f(x)$ for $x \in (2,5)$

So we can write

$g(x) \le g(x)$ for $x \in (2,5)$

We can directly apply the the limit inequality theorem theorem.

$\lim_{x \to 2} g(x) \le \lim_{x \to 2} f(x)$

Note that the theorem applies to 'accumulation points' which mean 'limit points' and that includes 2 and 5.

For the infinite case, it is convenient to look at limits of sequences. This theorem here gives a proof that the inequalities apply to the limit at infinity:

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inequality_Rule_for_Real_Sequences

EDIT: Note that I've edited since we're not actually using the squeeze theorem here as we're not saying the limits are equal.

Comment: Is this also true for infinity?If f(x)>g(x) for x€[0,infinity) then lim(f(x))>=lim(g(x)) at a where a€[0,infinity). Is infinity included here? Is a€[0,infinity] right? Because infinity is the extreme point and if limit is defined at infinity.

Comment: Yes, this is also true at infinity.

Comment: Note I've made some edits. It's not actually the squeeze theorem, because the squeeze theorem is really only about when the limits on the left and right become equal. Here we're just dealing with an inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Since we assume that we can continuously expand $f$ and $g$ to $[a,b]$ (in general, there is at most one continuous extension of a continuous function defined on an open interval, see my proof* below), the question is:
If $f,g\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ are continuous and $g(x)<f(x)$ for all $x\in(a,b)$, can we say that $g(x)\leq f(x)$ for all $x\in[a,b]$?

If this was not the case, $f-g$ would not be continuous. But since $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions, $f-g$ is continuous. So the answer is yes.

*Proof:
Let $f,g\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous and $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in(a,b)$. $X:=(f-g)^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\})$ is open, because $f-g$ is continuous. As $X$ is a subset of $\{a,b\}$, which has the (Lebesgue) measure zero, the measure of $X$ is also zero. Since the empty set is the only open set with measure zero, $X$ has to be the empty set.